# How to create a session between client and self-hosted WCF service

Tags: wcf, session, cookies, httpcontext, self-hosting

My goal is to keep track of clients with cookies and their sessions.  This is needed because I don't like WCF's builtin authentication process, where they are just give the generic login popup in the browser [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172992/sessions-in-self-hosted-wcf-services)].  I'm looking to have a login page and give the user the capability to logout.  I don't want to use IIS at all to host my service.  Is HttpContext the only way to maintain sessions/cookies?  Is this possible in a selfhosted WCF Service? Is this possible with `WebHttpBinding`?  The closest post I could find to this one was: [Sessions in self-hosted WCF services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172992/sessions-in-self-hosted-wcf-services) but it was unsatisfactory.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172992/sessions-in-self-hosted-wcf-services)[image: Authentication Popup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/67a1ea91-af62-44f8-9a6b-0982c7d05da8

Comment: Hi, please could you post a more clean code with your answer i figured the same problem. did you solved your problem?

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer This is super old. I wouldn't use WCF in this day and age.

Comment: I am working on a server app that must support tcp/http/netpipe for that reason I use WCF, any suggestion?